# Is there any difference between `x?.ToString("C")` and `$"{x:C}"`?

Tags: c#, tostring, string-interpolation

I'm trying to refactor code and wondering if `x?.ToString("C")` the same as `$"{x:C}"`? Thanks!

EDIT: 
The refactoring is part of changing the behavior of a legacy method named `ToCurrencyString`. Currently, it's behavior is not the desired default for the whole application but we wouldn't like to change whatever calls it. Hope that makes sense.

EDIT 2:
forgot to include that x can be `null`. Tried it and `"${x:C}"` converts it to `string.Empty` when `x = null`.

Comment: If you mean change `ToString()` to string interpolation, it's not worth it and will create an extra FormattableString object. From a semantic point, they are equivalent. As a possible refactoring, it's not worth considering.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes I'm trying it out but I might miss something not too obvious.

Comment: @PaoloGo why consider such a trivial change in the first place? This isn't exactly refactoring. The code doesn't improve in any way

Comment: If you are doing so, why don't you comment that you get the same or different output?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm changing from interpolation to ToString. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That string interpolation will not allocate a new FormattableString object. It compiles directly to `string.Format("{0:C}", x)`

Comment: @PaoloGo *why* ? What do you expect to gain from this? More readable code? Faster?

Comment: @canton7 making the change even less useful

Comment: Please see edit on why the need for refactoring.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't disagree with your overall argument, just pointing out that it's not *quite* as bad as you say. Although the `string.Format` call does go to the pain of getting a new `StringBuilder` from cache, it probably won't allocate (assuming `x` is a reference type)